# Unwanted extra destroy link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, destroy, nested-resources

I have an odd issue that is proving a bit difficult to remedy. I have an extra 'delete' link that shows up when I render a partial to destroy an 'item' which is part of a list so they are nested. The last(unwanted) delete link destroys the list itself instead of any item. I was hoping somebody could point out the inconsistency in my code or if I'm missing something because I can't get the form to render in any other way than what I have posted.

Just a simple to do app. An item belongs to a list and list has many items.

_item.html.erb

```
<p><%= item.content %> <%= link_to 'remove item', [@list, item],
                                  method: :delete,
                                  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></p>
```

Items controller

```
def destroy
    @list = List.find(params[:list_id])
    @item = @list.items.destroy(params[:id])
    redirect_to list_path(@list)
  end
```

Routes

```
resources :lists do
    resources :items
  end
```

Lists controller(destroy and show action)

```
 def destroy
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
    @list.destroy
    if @list.destroy
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  def show
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Lists show template

```
<section class"todo-list">
    <div class="row">
    <h2><%= @list.title %></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
            <h3><%= @list.description %></h3>
            <%= render :partial => 'items/form' %>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
        <h3>List Items</h3>
            <%= render :partial => @list.items %>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to see the rendered html codes of all the delete link in list? is all the link same in pattern as well as the last link?

Comment: In the `destroy` action of ItemsController, try replacing `@item = @list.items.destroy(params[:id])` with `@item = @list.items.find(params[:id])` and adding `@item.destroy` on the next line.

Comment: Same thing. I don't get this. When you delete with nested resources you're supposed to pass in both the id of both correct? Which is what I'm doing. So it adds a delete option for each item and then at the end of that list it also adds a delete link for the list itself. It must be a controller issue or something.